# Runtime error 7 while using Selenium with VBA for data entry into an online system

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, runtime-error

[image]I am new in VBA and Selenium. Wrote some lines using Selenium ChromeDriver that can open a online data management system, and log in successfully. I need to manually click on a map, and a table pops up where I need to input some data from a excel sheet using VBA. On that online page, I can access all the components using various methods (e.g., FindElementByName, FindElementByXPath, etc.) **except **the edit boxes and the dropdown elements on the popup table. I even can access the buttons on the bottom of the table. Only when I try to access the elements on the table, it give me the RUN TIME ERROR 7 OUT OF MEMORY. I have attached an image but hid some elements due to the confidential nature of the work. I know it is not a lot of information, but if someone can give me some directions I will highly appreciate it.

Thanks

I am using Selenium Chrome Driver

```
'Other Subs are here....

Sub Entry()

'I am using these methods to test

myChrome.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='ui-jqgrid-bdiv']//input[@name='input_ROUTE']").Value = "500"

myChrome.FindElementByName("input_ROUTE").SendKeys "500"

'These throws the Run-time error 7, Out of memory
'However, the same methods works for everything else except the elements on that table


End Sub`
```

Comment: A lot more will be needed, how to we know that myChrome has properly been given the HTML Doc Object? Now if you are trying to use myChrome without any prior code and myChrome is not a global variable that has the HTML Doc Object in it then that can also be the issue.

Comment: @RicardoA, Thank you! myChrome is a global variable and set as a Selenium Chromedriver. 
Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You may disregard my comment. In Selenium you do not need to call the document object.  Have you tried: `element=myChrome.find_element(By.NAME,"input_ROUTE")` and then  `element.setAttribute("value", "your value")`

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTML, it is possible that `input_ROUTE` is inside an `iframe` element, and the `XPath` you get is internal inside the iframe.

If this is the case, you need to first move into the iframe and then turn to the internal component. so:

```
myChrome.SwitchToFrame myChrome.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""loginIframe""]") 'Of course you need to change the XPath
myChrome.FindElementByName("input_ROUTE").SendKeys "500"
```